# How to use openvino for re-identification

Tags: openvino

I tried to bring a program related to re-identification and run it, but it doesn't work. I installed openvino and ran setupvars.bat, but only the following error message appears:

from openvino.inference_engine import IENetwork, IECore, IEPlugin, get_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openvino'

I don't know where the IENetwork, IECore, IEPluguin, get_version files are located. I can't find these files no matter how hard I look for them.

Let me know if you know a solution. And please let me know if you have any books or websites to study about re-identification. It's very difficult to study alone.(I'am a university student)

Answer (score 0):

If you face that error when running the setupvars, it means that You did not set up the OpenVINO pre-requisites/toolkit correctly.

This is the latest [OpenVINO guide](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/installation_guides.html), make sure to choose the correct OS according to yours.

You must be able to see the OpenVINO folder once you had installed the toolkit. The location should be as in the guide.

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKH57mvO9k0) is a great start for re-identification purpose.

Please note that, you won't be able to run anything if You did not set up the toolkit and pre-requisites properly.